# Find the best tile to place your base of operations from which you need to visit every point of interest such that total travel distance is minimal

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search, memoization

I received this interview question in a coding interview:

You are visiting a planet whose surface is represented by a m x n grid. On this grid, there are k points of interest as well as tiles that are not traversable. You need to find the best tile to place your base of operations from which you need to visit every point of interest where every time you visit a point of interest you need to come back to your base of operations and the goal is to place the base such that total travel distance is minimal. You can only move up, down, left, right. Every point of interest is reachable from every other point of interest, but not every tile on the grid is reachable from every other tile. Also the number k is significantly smaller than m x n

For example, if you have the grid:

X X X X X X
X P - - P X
X X X X X X

a valid answer would be any tile in the second row and between the first and last column exclusive since the total travel distance is 6 to visit all the points of interest and come back to the base.

Tiles can be placed on positions with the values of hyphen (can be traversed but is not a point of interest) or "P" (can be traversed and is a point of interest). Tiles with "X" are not traversable.

My solution:

For every candidate point, do a breadth first search to all the points of interest. The total distance for a candidate point is two times its distance to each point. I then returned the candidate point that (1) can visit all the points of interest and (2) has the minimum total travel distance.

The interviewer said that this solution works but said that it is possible to more efficiently compute the distances for the '-' points by using data from the points of interest. I was stuck and did not know how to do this.

I think using a memoization or dynamic programming approach might be the right solution but don't know how to come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is O(nmck), with c being the number of candidates. You can reduce this to O(nmk) as follows:

For each point of interest calculate the shortest distance to each reachable point. Sum up those distances for each point and then scan for the min (among the candidate points). If you want to know the real distance you have to multiply by two, because this calculates only the distances to each point of interest one way, which is sufficient to determine the best base placement.

So basically you did almost everything right, just started the search at the wrong end.